# How to install Z3 for Python3 in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, z3

I'm trying to run a program in python3 that has Z3 as a dependency (imports z3)

I was able to install the unstable version of Z3 (which is suppose to support Python3), but it install the libraries for python2.7 only.

[Here are the instructions](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README) at the project:

```
python scripts/mk_make.py
cd build
make
sudo make install
```

Does anybody know how to install Z3 work for Python3?

Thanks.

Comment: @lanzz the answer to that question is, summarily, the steps that tomyo has written above. tomyo is specifically having issues with the steps which are supposed to generate the Python 3 compatible files, but don't.

Comment: Just as a clerical clarification, what is the version of Python you are using to call `python scripts/mk_make.py`? Also, if you open a python interpreter at the console, what is the output of `import distutils.sysconfig; distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, overlooked it. Seeing that `python scripts/mk_make.py` generated a Makefile that installed the module for Python 2.7, I would guess `python` is a symlink to `python2.7`. @tomyo, try running `python3 scripts/mk_make.py` instead (follow the rest of the instructions unchanged) and see if it will end up in your Python 3 packages directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify scripts/mk_util.py in order to convert a few lines from Python2 to Python3 and also replace tab with spaces in other few lines, after that it worked!.

It seems somebody accidentally introduced changes not compatible with Python3.

I noticed *Leonardo de Moura* about this and he made a change in z3 git repo.

Here's a path just in case

```
--- z3-original/scripts/mk_util.py
+++ z3/scripts/mk_util.py
@@ -640,7 +640,7 @@

 def is_clang_in_gpp_form(cc):
     version_string = subprocess.check_output([cc, '--version'])
-    return version_string.find('clang') != -1
+    return str(version_string).find('clang') != -1

 def is_CXX_clangpp():
     if is_compiler(CXX, 'g++'):
@@ -1485,7 +1485,7 @@
                 print('Java Compiler:  %s' % JAVAC)
     else:
         global CXX, CC, GMP, FOCI2, CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS, EXAMP_DEBUG_FLAG
-   OS_DEFINES = ""
+        OS_DEFINES = ""
         ARITH = "internal"
         check_ar()
         CXX = find_cxx_compiler()
@@ -1508,7 +1508,7 @@
                 SLIBEXTRAFLAGS = '%s %s' % (SLIBEXTRAFLAGS,FOCI2LIB)
                 CPPFLAGS = '%s -D_FOCI2' % CPPFLAGS
             else:
-                print "FAILED\n"
+                print("FAILED\n")
                 FOCI2 = False
         if GIT_HASH:
             CPPFLAGS = '%s -DZ3GITHASH=%s' % (CPPFLAGS, GIT_HASH)
@@ -1536,21 +1536,21 @@
             SLIBFLAGS = '-dynamiclib'
         elif sysname == 'Linux':
             CXXFLAGS       = '%s -fno-strict-aliasing -D_LINUX_' % CXXFLAGS
-       OS_DEFINES     = '-D_LINUX'
+            OS_DEFINES     = '-D_LINUX'
             SO_EXT         = '.so'
             LDFLAGS        = '%s -lrt' % LDFLAGS
             SLIBFLAGS      = '-shared'
             SLIBEXTRAFLAGS = '%s -lrt' % SLIBEXTRAFLAGS
         elif sysname == 'FreeBSD':
             CXXFLAGS       = '%s -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FREEBSD_' % CXXFLAGS
-       OS_DEFINES     = '-D_FREEBSD_'
+            OS_DEFINES     = '-D_FREEBSD_'
             SO_EXT         = '.so'
             LDFLAGS        = '%s -lrt' % LDFLAGS
             SLIBFLAGS      = '-shared'
             SLIBEXTRAFLAGS = '%s -lrt' % SLIBEXTRAFLAGS
         elif sysname[:6] ==  'CYGWIN':
             CXXFLAGS    = '%s -D_CYGWIN -fno-strict-aliasing' % CXXFLAGS
-       OS_DEFINES     = '-D_CYGWIN'
+            OS_DEFINES     = '-D_CYGWIN'
             SO_EXT      = '.dll'
             SLIBFLAGS   = '-shared'
         else:
@@ -1586,7 +1586,7 @@
         config.write('SLINK_FLAGS=%s\n' % SLIBFLAGS)
         config.write('SLINK_EXTRA_FLAGS=%s\n' % SLIBEXTRAFLAGS)
         config.write('SLINK_OUT_FLAG=-o \n')
-   config.write('OS_DEFINES=%s\n' % OS_DEFINES)
+        config.write('OS_DEFINES=%s\n' % OS_DEFINES)
         if is_verbose():
             print('Host platform:  %s' % sysname)
             print('C++ Compiler:   %s' % CXX)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is wondering about this later on.

I created an alias from 'python' to 'python3' and then ran the install command on the z3 git repo.

```
alias python=python3 #alias for the script to use.
python scripts/mk_make.py --prefix=/home/leo
cd build
make
make install
```